Ошибка: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 не является приложением Win32
Пытаюсь подключиться к контроллеру ZkTeco proRF при помощи SDK. При запуске программы появляется ошибка: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 не является приложением Win32. Подскажите как исправить?
Вот код:
from zk import ZK

zk = ZK(ip='192.168.7.204', port=4370, timeout=50, password='', force_udp=True, ommit_ping=False)
zk.connect()
if zk:
    print(zk.get_device_name())

Ошибка:
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\chervonyi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\zk\base.py", line 257, in __send_command
    self.__data_recv = self.__sock.recv(response_size)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\work\Otchet\xlsFEditor.py", line 4, in <module>
    zk.connect()
  File "c:\Users\chervonyi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\zk\base.py", line 373, in connect
    cmd_response = self.__send_command(const.CMD_CONNECT)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\chervonyi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\zk\base.py", line 260, in __send_command
    raise ZKNetworkError(str(e))
zk.exception.ZKNetworkError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение


Установлена в виртуальное окружение? Добавьте в вопрос всю трассировку ошибки.

@AnnaBazueva-SPAM Виртуальное окружение не добавлено

Полный трейс ошибки в вопрос поместите. Может оно "plcommpro.dll" не может найти?

@CrazyElf, добавил

@Anton Тут много чего может быть. Почитайте в документации рекомендации по установке и обратите внимание на зависимости. Попробуйте установить в виртуальное окружение.

Ну точно, dll не может загрузить. Попробуйте полный dllpath указать к plcommpro.dll, ну и ещё можно модель контроллера при инициализации указать. Читайте доки.

Если доков нет, вот прям в исходнике можно параметры подсмотреть, какие можно в ZKAccess передать https://github.com/bdragon300/pyzkaccess/blob/master/pyzkaccess/main.py Я бы попробовал задать device_model и dllpath.

@CrazyElf, путь ZKAccess указал dllpath, ошибка по-прежнему такая же

Ну тогда не знаю. А сама dll не битая? )

@CrazyElf, с другими контроллера проблем по ней нету, функционал свой выполняет. Посмотрите пожалуйста, я нашел другую библиотеку, здесь уже другая ошибка, может с ней что посоветуете.
